# CSS Mozilla Firefox Bug

Tags: css, mozilla

I'm getting a weird css bug that I've never faced before. I use a list of images in a list element displayed inline. Everything works fine in Chrome but when browsing with Mozilla the last li element appears in a second line. Tried to change some values but no results! Anybody faced the same problem and solved it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N4NW.jpg

**CSS**

```
#std-signs ul {
  width: 736px;
  min-width: 736px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
#std-signs ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
#std-signs ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your html too. Or make a working demo at jsfiddle.com

Comment: Have you tried to remove the new line after the last LI, like so: `</li></ul>`

Comment: Solved it by using 1.46em instead of 1.5em. Weird that Firefox adds more space than Chrome for the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-cell;` instead of `display: inline-block;`

```
#std-signs ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

and to have margin to the right

```
#std-signs ul {
  width: 736px;
  min-width: 736px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  border-spacing: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, but "table-cell" wipes out the "margin-right" property.

Comment: Well, seems to work, but elements cannot be centered in the ul as they were in the picture in chrome.

Comment: apply padding value to ul li

Comment: Already tried that, and didn't work. I pasted the two screenshots the one on the other and noticed that "1.5em" in Firefox is a little bit "more" than in Chrome. I always use reset stylesheet because I know every browser has it's default values so never thought that this happens. I applied "1.46em" instead of "1.5" and seems to work fine.